# Systemd service sometimes crashes on startup

Tags: python, flask, centos7, gunicorn, systemd

I try to start my Gunicorn server using systemd.

The service definition is presented below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Flask application using gunicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/home/username/application/app.pid
User=username
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/application
Environment=PATH=/opt/venv/bin/
ExecStart=/opt/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /home/username/application/app.pid --workers 3 --bind unix:socket.sock -m 007 app:app
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that sometimes the app crashes on startup with the following messages in journalctl

```
gunicorn[28376]: [2019-08-22 15:01:48 +0300] [28379] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 28379)
gunicorn[28376]: [2019-08-22 15:01:48 +0300] [28381] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 28381)
gunicorn[28376]: [2019-08-22 15:01:48 +0300] [28376] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
gunicorn[28376]: [2019-08-22 15:01:48 +0300] [28376] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
systemd[1]: urzchat-dev.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
systemd[1]: urzchat-dev.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Unit urzchat-dev.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: urzchat-dev.service failed.
```

This behavior occurs about 1/3 of all starts.

Tell me, why might that be and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Linux and its usage should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The `Environment` directive should be enclosed as a string:

```
Environment="PATH=/opt/venv/bin/"
```

Also, you may add a condition for your network being connected to the internet before start:

```
After=network.target network-online.target
```

Comment: It seems to have solved my problem. But why sometimes the service started with incorrect parameters?

Comment: Dunno, really, I guess you should add `LogLevel=debug` to `/etc/systemd/system.conf` as default is just `info`.